# Are Turing machines with a limited but exponential tape decidable?

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

The Halting problem for Turing machines which work on a tape of at most $k$ cells can be solved: There is a limited number of distinct configurations available, providing an upper bound of steps before nontermination is determined.

Now let us give each cell an exponent: It stores how often the symbol in the cell is to be repeated, i.e. we use a run-length encoding. The machine then works on this tape under preservation of the exponent.

The number of distinct values is still limited to $k$, but the effective tape length is no longer bounded. I'm fairly certain this class of Turing machines suffers from the Halting problem just like regular, unbounded machines do, but I'm looking for a concise proof.

$k$ can be assumed to be $\geq 7$.

Example:

Starting in configuration $x^3$ A $y^2$ $z^5$ with $\delta(A,y) = w,right,A$ and $\delta(A,z) = v,left,B$, execution will be:

- $x^3$ A $y^2$ $z^5$
- $x^3$ $w^1$ A $y^1$ $z^5$
- $x^3$ $w^2$ A $z^5$
- $x^3$ $w^1$ B $w^1$ $v^1$ $z^4$

In this example, the maximum number of cells used so far is 4 (or 5 if the head is seen as a splitting point), seen in the final step. The total effective tape length is $3+2+5=10$, but this number is not limited for our purposes.

Just for curiosity, to make the example machine nonhalting, replace $\delta(A,z) = v,right,A$ and add $\delta(A,\sqcup) = u,right,A$, and the machine will increase the exponent of $u$ indefinitely.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, it seems a basic approach might be to consider the exponent an encoded representation of an unrestricted tape, circumventing the length restriction.

Comment: You can probably simulate a [counter machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_machine) with two counters using your model.

Comment: What is the difference between this model and a turing machine with 2k cells, one of which contains values and the other contains run lengths?  It seems to me that your exponential tape machine with length k must be able to do a subset of the things a normal turing machine with length 2k can do.

Comment: This is essentially an extension of a Linear Bounded Automaton. Since their acceptance problem is decidable whereas the general model isn't, then they aren't equivalent.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_machine even contains a section  `A Turing machine can be simulated by two stacks', which I'm having some trouble understanding yet, but might be an answer.

Comment: @D.W. While the exponent is unlimited, the machine must still be finite in states. The machine still operates on single symbols, not a symbol plus exponent.

Comment: @D.W. I've added an example that should make it clear.

Comment: @CortAmmon We would need an infinite number of symbols describing all possible exponents in the second cell. If that were not the case, the (decidable) 2$k$-TM could simulate the bounded exponential tape machine, yes.

Comment: @Ryan Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Out of curiosity: how did you come by this variant of a Turing machine?

Comment: @PJ I'm currently writing my thesis about Busy Beavers, where this kind of tape is very common. Usually an encoding of several symbols into one symbol is used, such that repeated 'words' appear, which then get an exponent. Interestingly, by this approach, all of the halting machines can be simulated in such limited conditions, even when their 'normal' tape would be of length $> 10^{10000}$.